# VBA-Excel Formula Reference- Calculation Refresh

Tags: vba, excel

This is a follow up to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39210027/vba-inter-workbook-actions-errors-everytime-i-fix-something/39210195#39210195). I successfully was able to open a different workbook on a different drive, copy the data in a range as a picture, and then paste it in `ThisWorkbook`.The problem I'm running into now is that the `.CopyPicture` I'm using is capturing the cell values as they calculate so it ends up looking like a bunch of `#N/A Requesting Data...` values.

I've used a few different things to see if I can get the formulas to calculate before copying them, but it seems like the spreadsheet will not follow through with the calculation until the macro is no longer running.

I checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355851/excel-calculation-refresh-from-vba) but I'm not entirely sure how to implement the `if Application.CalculationState is xLdone then loop else wait`. Any help with this?

Original Code:

```
Dim BBPic As Workbook
Dim test As Workbook
Set BBPic = Application.Workbooks.Open("\\OtherDrive\Shared\OtherGroup\DailySheet.xlsx")
Set test = ThisWorkbook

BBPic.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:E16").CopyPicture
test.Sheets("Summary").Range("B64").PasteSpecial
```

First attempt:

```
Dim BBPic As Workbook
Dim test As Workbook
Set BBPic = Application.Workbooks.Open("\\OtherDrive\Shared\OtherGroup\DailySheet.xlsx")
Set test = ThisWorkbook

BBPic.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:E16").CopyPicture
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00"))
test.Sheets("Summary").Range("B64").PasteSpecial
Workbooks("DailySheet.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Second attempt:

```
Dim BBPic As Workbook
Dim test As Workbook
Set BBPic = Application.Workbooks.Open("\\OtherDrive\Shared\OtherGroup\DailySheet.xlsx")
Set test = ThisWorkbook

BBPic.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:E16").CopyPicture
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
test.Sheets("Summary").Range("B64").PasteSpecial
Workbooks("DailySheet.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Final attempt:

```
Dim BBPic As Workbook
Dim test As Workbook
Set BBPic = Application.Workbooks.Open("\\OtherDrive\Shared\OtherGroup\DailySheet.xlsx")
Set test = ThisWorkbook

BBPic.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:E16").CopyPicture
ActiveSheet.Calculate
test.Sheets("Summary").Range("B64").PasteSpecial
Workbooks("DailySheet.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
```

EDIT: 4th attempt using the `Application.CalculationState = xlDone`

```
Dim BBPic As Workbook
Dim test As Workbook
Set BBPic = Application.Workbooks.Open("\\OtherDrive\Shared\OtherGroup\DailySheet.xlsx")
Set test = ThisWorkbook

BBPic.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Do Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone: DoEvents: Loop

ActiveSheet.Range("B2:E16").CopyPicture
test.Sheets("Summary").Range("B64").PasteSpecial
Workbooks("DailySheet.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Comment: "if Application.CalculationState is xLdone then loop else wait" basically means `Do Until Application.CalculationState = xlDone: DoEvents: Loop` (in case you didn't know, colon `:` separates statements in VBA)

Comment: I edited in my 4th attempt using it but it did not seem to work.

Comment: are you using bloomberg formulas?

Comment: @cyboashu yes. It's funny because I'm stepping into the code and after I open up the sheet, no matter what I do it won't follow through with the calculation, but once I end the macro, the calculations go through.

Comment: here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298934/vba-waiting-for-bloomberg-bdp-calls-to-finish and this one too; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669845/bloomberg-data-doesnt-populate-until-excel-vba-macro-finishes

Comment: @cyboashu So I broke it out into 2 macros and it worked. Referencing this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669845/bloomberg-data-doesnt-populate-until-excel-vba-macro-finishes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I broke my macro into two, utilizing `Application.Run` and `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")` thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669845/bloomberg-data-doesnt-populate-until-excel-vba-macro-finishes) and @cyboashu for informing me. What I was experiencing was true: Bloomberg data will not refresh unless the macro has ended, so you have to break it out into 2 macros with the first refreshing the data and the second performing what you want done.

```
Sub OpenDailySheet()
'
'Macro
'

'

Dim BBPic As Workbook
Set BBPic = Application.Workbooks.Open("\\OtherDrive\Shared\OtherGroup\DailySheet.xlsx")
Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "PasteChart"


End Sub

Sub PasteChart()

Dim test As Workbook
Set test = ThisWorkbook

Workbooks("DailySheet.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:E16").CopyPicture
test.Sheets("Summary").Range("B64").PasteSpecial
Workbooks("DailySheet.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```