# VBA: How to give Excel time to calculate before jumping into the next command?

Tags: vba, bloomberg

I am using Bloomberg's BDP formula to pull prices, which generally takes about 1-4 seconds. However, VBA runs the next line of codes before the price pull has been completed, resulting in errors. I am wondering if there is a way to tell Excel to take 5 seconds to run:

Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"

The complete code is:

```
Sub update()

Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"

Worksheets("BB").Range("B2:G1000").Copy
Worksheets("Upload").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: You could try using `Application.Wait`. Although you're going to have to include your code if you want help figuring out *why* this happening.

Comment: Possibly answered by https://stackoverflow.com/q/10279404/1531971 but as suggested we don't know until we see the code.

Comment: Effectively, I am trying to provide a few seconds of delay for Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData" to complete before running the next line of code. It is a simple script that involves pulling prices, then copy-and-paste the updated prices to a new sheet in the same workbook, then save and close the workbook. The complete code is: Sub update()

Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"

Worksheets("BB").Range("B2:G1000").Copy
Worksheets("Upload").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub

Comment: If `RefreshAllStaticData` is in the same VBA project you're coding in, you can invoke it like this: `RefreshAllStaticData`. No need for `Application.Run` and stringly-typed method names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA: Waiting for Bloomberg BDP calls to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298934/vba-waiting-for-bloomberg-bdp-calls-to-finish)

Comment: @HenryCao you asked the same question yesterday - I suggest you delete one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Again, we haven't seen all your code (since we don't know what `Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"` entails) but this:

```
Sub update()

Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"

'Refresh everything
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
'Wait 5 seconds just in case
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))

Worksheets("BB").Range("B2:G1000").Copy
Worksheets("Upload").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: How do I find out the code for Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"? Bloomberg Excel API is an external Excel API provided by Bloomberg that grabs data provided by Bloomberg.

Comment: "RefreshAllStaticData" has to be a subroutine in your workbook, somewhere.

Comment: You don't know if it's going to take 5 or 20 seconds. You should use `onTime` instead.